# Show overlay only in images which are not hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here when I hover on the some image I want to show up this `img-overlay`(Change opacity to 1) only on those images which are not hovered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.img-overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 210px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
transition: .5s ease;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="team-member">
<div class="img-overlay"></div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
<h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">Zero</h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="team-member">
<div class="img-overlay"></div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
<h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">one</h4>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="team-member">
<div class="img-overlay"></div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
<h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">two</h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="team-member">
<div class="img-overlay"></div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
<h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">Three</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these script and style to your code

```
<script>
        jQuery(".team-member").mouseover(function(){
            jQuery(".img-overlay").addClass("overlay-in");
            jQuery(this).addClass("current");
        });
        jQuery(".team-member").mouseleave(function(){
            jQuery(".img-overlay").removeClass("overlay-in");
            jQuery(this).removeClass("current");
        });
    </script>

    <style>

    .img-overlay.overlay-in{ opacity:1; }
    .team-member.current .img-overlay{ opacity:0!important; }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're off to a good start. All you need is the team-member to have `position:relative` to make each `img-overlay` have the right position.
And then set the opacity 1 by default and change it to 0 on hover.
That's all.

```css
.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 210px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;                       /* changed */
  transition: .5s ease;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.team-member {                      /* new */
  position:relative;
}

.team-member:hover .img-overlay {   /* new */
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="team-member">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
      <h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">Zero</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="team-member">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
      <h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">one</h4>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="team-member">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
      <h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">two</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="team-member">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Aarya Guta">
      <h4 class="team-title" style="color: #404444;">Three</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u, but here in my requirement all the overlay div should in invisible(opacity:0), when user starts hovering the images then the opacity should change

Answer (score 0):

One Solution could be to hide overlay when parent div is hoverd, for example

```
$("div.col-xs-3").on('hover', function(){  
    $(this).find('.img-overlay').first().hide();
});
```